# Does a 97 Mazda Demio Have a Cabin Filter, if so Where is it?

Tags: mazda, cabin-filter

I have a 97 Mazda Demio 121. Imported from Japan. Do these use a cabin filter, and if so where is it located? I have looked behind the glove box, and around the driver's side, but can't see anything in the obvious spots

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Raise the hood and look for the cabin air filter box on the passenger side below the windshield. It's behind the rear rubber seal that touches the hood when the hood is closed. You'll find it directly below the air slots that are under the wipers. Unsnap the two clips that hold the box closed and flip the door open to replace the filter.